# How to format computer hard drive to ntfs

Tags: boot, gparted, ntfs, format

So I have ubuntu right now and I'm trying to get windows by using a bootable usb but when I try to install windows it says that the hard drive has to be formated to NTFS so I have tried formatting it in gparted but it says it's busy. What do I do now?

Comment: Boot from a Live USB distribution. One cannot format the drive you booted from - it's "busy".

Comment: @Kulfy I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

Boot from a Ubuntu LiveUSB and run [gparted](https://gparted.org). Although the [relevant section of the gparted documentation](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-specify-partition-type) does not mention it, you can [make a new partition in gparted to be NTFS](https://www.lifewire.com/use-gparted-to-partition-hard-drive-2205693).